# How to make chips using bootstrap 4 in input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make and input field with drop-down,the input field is of `type=email` in the drop-down i am getting mail ids from my database what i am trying to do is when user clicks on any drop-down it gets  populated into that input field but drop-down should not close becauseit is a multi-select dropdown when ever user focus-out from the drop-down it gets closed

When user selects any drop-down that option should get selected or checked

and inside that input field it can come as chip or token as how it comes in gmail when we enter more then one mail ids

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


<div class="input-group mt-3 mb-3">

  <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="mail id">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
     Email id
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">abc@gmail.com</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">egf@gmail.com</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">123@gmail.com</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and in input field email should come as `chips`

Comment: Take a look: https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/hVDNb4

Comment: @MebinJoe that is happning on click of button i want to do it on tab press or enter of my gmail

Comment: There are 100s of plugins that do just what you're asking - though you might find them more easily if you use the more common term: `tokenise`

Comment: @freedomn-m i am not using angular i can do this in plain html using java-script and bootstrap?

Comment: @freedomn-m `tokenizeinput` selects values from predefined list which is not the case here

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `tokenizeinput` but the process of converting input text to what you call a "chip" is also called "tokenise" / "tokenize".  Will help you google a solution.  As it stands, your question is too broad.  Perhaps you could add the javascript code you've attempted.

Comment: @freedomn-m please don't say my question is to broad, i don't have any knowledge regarding this that's why i have put up the question

Comment: Are you talking about this: http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/examples.html

Comment: @MayankPandeyz yup like that only but my form is different please check the edit i have made,that will let you know what i am trying to do

Comment: Sorry, I don't saw your edit. let me update my answer. @dheerajkumar

Comment: @Prabusamvel yupp, i have an input field as well as dropdown when user selects any options from dropdown then it will get populated in input field,or there is no need for validate the email,because i am getting all the mail ids from database in dropdown

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
var selected = [];
var availableTags = [
 "abc@gmail.com",
 "abc1@gmail.com",
 "abc2@gmail.com",
 "abc3@gmail.com",
 "abc4@gmail.com"
 ];
 
  $( function() {
    $("#tags").autocomplete({
      source: availableTags,
      select: function( event, ui){
        var value = ui.item.value;
        selected.push(value);
        refreshDiv();
        var i = availableTags.indexOf(value);
        availableTags.splice(i, 1);
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#tags").focusout();
        $("#tags").val('');
      }
    });
  });
  
  function refreshDiv(){
 $("#emails").val(selected.join(','));
   var email_html = selected.map(function(f, i){
  return "<span class='btn btn-info btn-sm' style='margin: 3px;'>"+f+"&nbsp;&nbsp; <span onclick=\"removeEmail('"+f+"')\" style='color:red'>x</span></span>";
 });
   $("#email-html").html(email_html);
  }
  
  function removeEmail(email){
    availableTags.push(email);
   var i = selected.indexOf(email);
   selected.splice(i, 1);
   refreshDiv();
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
   <div id="email-html"></div>
   <input type="hidden" name="emails" id="emails"/>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
   <div class="ui-widget">
     <input id="tags">  
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yuppp,like this but why can i make that a chip like it was in your previous solution,and if i can do it without any plugin and also that select field is also getting the values populated when i click on any drop-down

Comment: is that ok for you?

Comment: hey why to make another div to show the data,what i am trying to do is remove that  `bootstrap-select` plugin and then have a input field with dropdown by which when i click on any dropdown it gets selected and its value store into that input field

Comment: I'm not getting you. do you want the exact bootstrap-select functionality without using it?

Comment: yup something like a drop-down with multiselect and when i click on any drop-down it gets populated inside that input field like what your 1st solution

Comment: hey can you please help me out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55846400/appended-new-row-is-not-behaving-like-previous-one-row

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest to rely on a battle tested solution rather than building your own!
Have a look at jQuery TagEditor:

Documentation: https://goodies.pixabay.com/jquery/tag-editor/demo.html

```js
const isEmail = input => /^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/.test(input);

$('#email-tags').tagEditor({
    placeholder: 'Enter tags ...',
    beforeTagSave: (field, editor, tags, tag, val) => {
    
      // make sure it is a formally valid email
      if (!isEmail(val)) {
        console.log(`"${val}" is not a valid email`);
        return false;
      }
    }
});
```

```css
@import url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tag-editor/1.0.20/jquery.tag-editor.css");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/caret/1.3.4/jquery.caret.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tag-editor/1.0.20/jquery.tag-editor.js"></script>


<input id="email-tags" />
```

Comment: sir i have edited my post you please check what is i am looking for

Comment: just checked, code works just fine... I have added a log to show that entered value is not a valid email. Thank you for your comment!

Comment: Thanks !! Can you provide same code in Angularjs without Angular material?

Comment: Thanks! Very useful library.

Answer (score 0):

Hey bro use jquery focus out function to handle. so that i will work when u focus out using tab.

```
$( "element which you want" )
  .focusout(function() {
   //statement which is to be executed.
  })
```

Comment: i am trying to do it same like we have in gmail compose message

Comment: @dheerajkumar use the focus out  function it will execute when you press tab key.

Comment: i am facing issue while making chip with JS :(

Comment: @dheerajkumar give us the html code which u have worked so that we can help you to achive what u want.

Comment: i have uploaded the HTML code,that input field i want to make chat whatever email i enter then i want to show it as chips